# npm install not working, module not found, tried seemingly everything

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, npm, mariadb

I have had no issues with installing modules up until now, and I'm not sure what went wrong, as I haven't changed my workflow at all.

I ran:

```
npm i --save mariadb
```

in the root directory of my Node project. Then I imported this module:

```
const mariadb = require("mariadb")
```

When I try to run, though, I get

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mariadb'
```

Looking in node_modules, mariadb indeed is in there, but then looking in package.json, mariadb is not listed in dependencies. I then tried running

```
npm install --save mariadb
```

in the src directory to same effect. Then tried

```
npm install -g mariadb
```

to same effect. Then tried

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Same effect, and I also get this error (I assume it must be related somehow):

```
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/codyray/github.com/cody-a-ray/neighbors/client/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /Users/codyray/github.com/cody-a-ray/neighbors/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
```

Also, after that last command, every package.json file has the following error:

```
Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': Unable to load schema from 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND schemastore.azurewebsites.net.
```

I have no idea what any of this means. Seems very cryptic.
I then tried just manually adding mariadb to my package.json and running

```
npm install --save
```

again, to no effect.

God help me

Comment: Did you configured any firewall, or VPN, or did anything on your network changed lately? Other thing to look into is did you test it with other packages (that you don't have) to see whether it is a mariadb only problem? And what version of npm/node are you using? have you consider updating it?

Comment: I actually was using a VPN, and then realized that might be a problem, so I disconnected from my VPN, deleted node_modules, installed everything again, and the same errors happen. I upgraded node. And it looks like this is not just a problem with mariadb as I am now having trouble using any new modules. All modules I was already using are still working though, seemingly.

Comment: Have you tried: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-macos-catalina-anansewaa-38b536389e8d ? Looks convincing to me. I don't use a mac though so I can't test this solution.

Comment: So if you are having problems with new modules as well I definitely suspect of some sort of network issue. You mention that you disabled VPN and still not working, any proxy on the network you are using? Do you have the means of testing it with a different connection (maybe using cell phone network instead)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

```
npm install mariadb --save
```

I see you are putting in the wrong order, for more information run this command on your console:

```
npm help install
```

Comment: Tried this and same effect